# Double hover animation - is that possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a CSS animation where a card is opened, not from one side, but two sides. So there is a center part and two side "flaps". Both will start folded over the center part.

I know you can do a CSS hover which if I go over it one side will open. At that moment you have e.g. the left side open and the right side is still on top of the middle part. Is it in any way possible to do another hover animation so the right side flips also open and the whole card is visible?

The other way I can see it work is that I click on the back of the left flap, it opens and then I click on the right flap to open it. But I guess that has to be done in Javascript?

Comment: What code have you started with? If you can write your HTML such that the tags for the sides are either nested inside the center, or come after the center, then you should be able to write CSS rules that target the sides when you mouse over the center.

Comment: If I understood desired case correctly, when user clicks the main object, you should trigger .show(animate) for left and right, 2 times.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. How? Good question! There are various approaches. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @IvanRubinson i have tried with hoover. I can get it like i open a book or a card, so the left side opens. The part i need to try now is to get both sides open simultaneously or i have to click 2 times to open one side at a time.

Comment: Show us your code @ray55nl

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for something like this, you can tweak the code from here to get your desired results.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.content {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    perspective: 2000px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.left {
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: 1.5s;
}

.right {
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: .5s;
}

.content:hover .left {
    transform: rotateY(-125deg);
    transition: .5s;
}

.content:hover .right {
    transform: rotateY(125deg);
    transition: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: example]

The way i pictured it is, you start als 1. Then you click on it and the sides flip open each to one side and it becomes like 2. the way i like to see it is like you open a book but not just one side but both

Answer (score 0):

@Vektor

That was exactly what i was looking for, thank you!

My end result is:

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    background: url(achtergrond\ omtrek.png);
    width: 1850px;
    height: 929px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    background: url(center.png);
    width: 563px;
    height: 825px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    perspective: 2000px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.left,
.right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 531px;
    height: 721px;
    top: 5%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.left {
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: 1.5s;
}

.right {
    transform-origin: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.content:hover .left {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    background: url(left.png);
    transition: .5s;
}

.content:hover .right {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: url(right.png);
    transition: 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: That's great and I was happy to help, you can take it a step further by adding a background for the flop, if it's necessary of course :)